# Would all melee PC attacks doing alignment damage be unbalanced at low levels?

Tags: damage-types, pathfinder-2e

For a campaign, I am currently discussing giving the PCs the ability to convert all melee and unarmed damage into alignment damage instead of normal physical, slashing, etc. damage.

One of the players suddenly realized that that makes the attacks extremely powerful and unbalanced at first level and lower levels.

Now I am wondering: is there anything I have overlooked that means having this ability starting at lower levels or level 1 could unbalance things in a normal Golarion campaign?

Comment: Is the conversion optional, or forced on every hit? What about ranged weapons? Thrown weapons? How does this ability interact with others that allow the same thing? What if the characters are True Neutral? Are they then disadvantaged?

Comment: @yogozuno that one rule was primarily for evil and good chars (until a true alignment change it was that they stayed wirt rhwir former „power“ and only when good/evil again it changes. Its only melee and brawl. And first idea was they can choose at start of the turn to turn it off. But if too powerful can also make it permanent. If also tol powerful then iam not surehow to proceed

Comment: Only evil and good? What about Law vs Chaos? If a character is, for instance, Lawful Good, will their damage be Good, Lawful or both? I suspect you might not have considered all angles here.

Comment: @YogoZuno as the question got edited its alignment damage thus chaos and law also possible. In my case they have to decide on one alignment (as example angels, demons,.... don't do BOTH alignments they usually do either good or evil damage not also law/order)

Answer (score 2):

In the end, how much this rule changes the game's balance will depend on what the players face. The more enemies they face with vulnerability to the aligned damage types, the more useful the ability will be, and the more impact it will have. It will also depend quite a lot on the range of alignments the players take.

For instance, most types of fiend are vulnerable to good damage, but not evil, chaotic or lawful. If you plan on throwing a lot of fiends at the players, and they are all good, they will potentially have a large advantage, especially at lower levels where aligned damage is quite rare.

On the other hand, if you throw mostly opponents that are not differently affected by aligned damage, this capability will make little or no change to how they perform.

Another perhaps unintended consequence of this change is that damage from melee weapon or unarmed attacks is no longer physical damage. This will mean that, from a very early level, the characters will be able to bypass any physical resistance to damage, such as [Vampires](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=399) have.

Note that physical damage resistance seems quite rare in 2nd ed Pathfinder. The design philosophy seems to have mostly been to convert 1st ed DR to a vulnerability to the attack that bypassed DR. For instance, lycanthropes used to have DRx/Silver, but now have weakness x Silver. See the [Werewolf](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=411) for an example.

Comment: A player of mine mentioned that it bypasses DR?

Comment: @ThomasE. Under 2e, there isn't really any DR. Instead, creatures that had DR under 1e will usually have a vulnerability to what used to break the DR, rather than a resistance to damage. There are still some critters that have resistance to physical damage, and this change WILL bypass that. I'll update the answer to mention this.

Comment: It might be worth referencing the new dedications which have a feat that lets them use a special attack to deal extra damage under some conditions and convert it all to an aligned type. Ref: Knight Vigilant's [Blade of the Crimson Oath](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1101) for converting to positive against undead, Hellknight's [Blade of Law](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1080) for converting to Law against someone you witnessed breaking/disrespecting law or being disorderly (Both are level 12 feats and require two actions and conditionally gain extra damage)

Comment: First I've heard of those :) Also, they are a little different - two actions for one attack that does typed damage, not convert all damage on the fly with no extra actions.